# PHP - Pass by reference function argument

Tags: php, function, reference, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [default method argument with class property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823018/default-method-argument-with-class-property)

I'm writing a recursive function and just for ease of use I want the first call of the function to accept a default argument. This value has to be the address of an object member variable. See below full code:

```
class Test{
    public $hierarchy = array( );
    public function addPath( $path, &$hierarchy ){
        $dirs = explode( '/', $path );
        if( count( $dirs ) == 1 ){
            if( is_dir( $path ) )
                $hierarchy[ $dirs[ 0 ] ] = '';
            else
                $hierarchy[ $path ] = '';
            return $hierarchy;
        }
        $pop = array_shift( $dirs );
        $hierarchy[ $pop ] = $this->addPath( 
            implode( '/', $dirs ), $hirearchy[ $pop ] );

        return $hierarchy;
    }
}

$t = new Test( );
$t->addPath( '_inc/test/sgsg', $t->hierarchy );
print_r( $t->hierarchy );
```

Now, what I would like to do here ideally is add a default value:

```
public function addPath( $path, &$hierarchy = $this->hierarchy ){
```

So that I can call it like this:

```
$t->addPath( '_inc/test/sgsg' );
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in tst.php on line 9
```

I've been trying a few things with no success. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Here's [the documentation](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-153) that says why this doesn't work. _"The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call."_

Comment: @Wiseguy thanks. didn't realise you couldn't use variables for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do this, the parser does not (cannot!) cater for resolving variables in function definitions.

You can however define the function with `&$hierarchy = null` in the definition and use `is_null` to see if a value was passed. (unless your referenced value will sometimes be null, then you'll need another workaround)

If `is_null` returns true then you can assign `$hierarchy = &$this->hierarchy`

---

After a quick discussion in PHP chat, using `func_num_args()` might be useful here. It doesn't count args that are populated with defaults, so you can safely pass variables that contain `null` by reference, and use this function to determine if the value in `$hierarchy` came from a passed parameter, or by the default. (thanks @NikiC)

Comment: hi, i tried using null as the default value and adding this line:  $hirerarchy = is_null( $hierarchy ) ? &$this->hierarchy : $hierarchy; but i get the a syntax error for the & on that line. will give func_num_args a go now thanks