# PHP Using $this->variable as Class Method Parameter Default Value

Tags: php, class, variables, default

Ok so this seems like a pretty dumb question but PHP Is telling me I can't do this,  or rather my IDE...

In the below example its telling me I can't use $this->somevar as the default value for the method.

ie...

```
class something {

public somevar = 'someval';

private function somefunc($default = $this->somevar) {

}



}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [default method argument with class property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823018/default-method-argument-with-class-property)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm afraid your IDE is correct. This is because "the default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a **class member** or a function call." — *[Function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)*

You'll need to do something like this:

```
class something {

    public $somevar = 'someval';

    private function somefunc($default = null) {
        if ($default === null) {
            $default = $this->somevar;
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be written using the [ternary operator](https://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
$default = $default ?: $this->somevar;
```

Comment: You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) to do it more compact

Comment: Tiny error `public somevar = 'someval';` is missing the $ and should be `public $somevar = 'someval';` I copied and pasted to just re-craft it and lost about 30 seconds flummoxed. Posted this here just in case another numbskull comes along!

Comment: Wow, looks like both Victor and I copied the OP and never noticed the mistake! Thanks, fixed :-)

Answer (score 5):

> "The default value [of a function argument] must be a constant expression, not (for example)
>   a variable, a class member or a function call."

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
class something {

    public somevar = 'someval';

    private function somefunc($default = null) {
        $default = ValueResolver::resolve($default, $this->somevar); // returns $this->somevar value if $default is empty
    }
}
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples

Comment: Why would you add an entire 3rd party package just to do something as simple as `$default = $default ?: $this->somevar;`?

Comment: There are few additional methods for typecasting it it. Also I plan to do this library more complex to avoid usage of `isset` function in code

Comment: @harryg It also will be useful for automate some parts of framework with it